# VBA- get field names and check if they exist in the temp table

Tags: vba, ms-access

Any help will be be appreciated. I am trying to get this code to work. I am needing to get the field names of a temp table and check if they exist using another permanent table.   My question is, is arresting holding the variable, where do I actually put in the field names for it to check. ?  If I am not going to add the field names WILL the code do it for me?   How DO I call the function in order to do this.  The function accepts and argument called strfield and what is confusing me is the get names variable is arrStrings.  Shouldn't they match?

```
Sub Example()
Dim objRecordset As ADODB.Recordset
Dim arrStrings(1 To 100) As String 
Dim intIndex As Integer 
Dim i As Integer 

Set objRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset
objRecordset.ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.Connection
objRecordset.Open ("MyTable1")
intIndex = 1
'loop through table fields 
For i = 0 To objRecordset.Fields.Count - 1
arrStrings(intIndex) = objRecordset.Fields.Item(i).Name      
intIndex = intIndex + 1      
Next i
End Sub 


' this is the function that checks the exists

Function CheckExists(ByVal strField As String) As Boolean 
Dim objRecordset As ADODB.Recordset
Dim i As Integer 

Set objRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset
objRecordset.ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.Connection
objRecordset.Open ("MyTable2")
'loop through table fields 
For i = 0 To objRecordset.Fields.Count - 1
'check for a match      
If strField = objRecordset.Fields.Item(i).Name Then       
'exit function and return true      
CheckExists = True      
Exit Function      
End If      
Next i
'return false 
CheckExists = False
End Function
```

Comment: Where is the code from ?  And it seems like the same table is being used for both queries ?  There seems to be "extra" code between the two methods - is that real or a mistake ?

Comment: I edited it and change the table in the function to mytable2. The second part is a function check  ooh I see it i WILL REMOVE.  TY!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
Option Explicit


Sub Example()
    Dim objRecordset As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim intNumExist As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    Set objRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset
    objRecordset.ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.Connection
    objRecordset.Open ("MyTempTable")

    'loop through table fields, see if they exist in other table
    For i = 0 To objRecordset.Fields.Count - 1
        intNumExist = intNumExist + CheckExists(objRecordset.Fields.Item(i).Name)
    Next i

    Debug.Print intNumExist & "fields exist in both tables"

End Sub

Function CheckExists(ByVal strField As String) As Integer
    Dim objRecordset As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim i As Integer

    Set objRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset
    objRecordset.ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.Connection
    objRecordset.Open ("MyPermTable")
    'loop through table fields
    For i = 0 To objRecordset.Fields.Count - 1
        'check for a match ?
        If strField = objRecordset.Fields.Item(i).Name Then
            'exit function and return true (1)
            CheckExists = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
    'return false
    CheckExists = False

    CheckExists = Abs(CheckExists)
End Function
```

Not sure what your end-goal is, but this should give you a point in the right direction. If you really want to see whether each individual field exists in both tables, then an array like you had before is a good idea.

Comment: Thank you!  Its for validating the data going into Sharepoint list table that is connected to Sharepoint... i need to know if the user deleted a column prior to fully importing the data.  the data is coming in from excel using a docked transfer spreadsheet and I couldn't figure out how to validate between Excel and Access without setting up an elaborate table schema. I will try this out now and let you know how it goes... Thanks I hope it works!  It looks great.

Comment: how do I call  yours though. i am not good with boolean calls and I do not know how to call it.  Can you assist?

Comment: So I call it in the first section.  The way it is set up now, it will check one field at a time.  So you could do something like this (sorry, guess I cannot have code format in a comment):  If  CheckExists(objRecordset.Fields.Item(i).Name) = 1 Then.... or, If  CheckExists("fieldName") = 1 Then.... I have it set up as 1 or 0 in case you wanted to tell if 6 out of 7 fields matched, etc.  You could just change the function to return a Boolean instead of an integer and get True/False.  I can paste the code for that if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

I would be inclined to return all of the fields in the other table in a dictionary, so you avoid the repeated querying while you're looping over the first recordset.

Untested:

```
Sub Example()

    Dim objRecordset As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim arrStrings(1 To 100) As String
    Dim intIndex As Integer
    Dim f As Field, dict As Scripting.Dictionary

    Set objRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset
    objRecordset.ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.Connection
    objRecordset.Open "MyTable1"

    'get the list of fields for the other table
    Set dict = GetTableFields("MyOtherTable")

    For Each f In objRecordset.Fields
        If dict.Exists(f.Name) Then
            'have matching field in MyOtherTable
        Else
            'no matching field in MyOtherTable
        End If
    Next f

End Sub

'return all the field names for the provided table name
Function GetTableFields(ByVal sTable As String) As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim objRecordset As ADODB.Recordset
    'add reference to "Microsoft Scripting Runtime"
    Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim f As Field

    Set objRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset
    objRecordset.ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.Connection
    'you don't need any records: just the fields
    objRecordset.Open "select * from " & sTable & " where false"
    'collect all the field names...
    For Each f In objRecordset.Fields
        dict.Add f.Name
    Next f
    Set GetTableFields = dict 'return the dictionary (note "Set"...)
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks!  I hadn't thought of that.  I will test yours now as well.  In your code since its not boolean how do I call it.. I am sorry , my weakness is calling functions. Can you explain?

Comment: Ahh ha!! :)  Set dict = GetTableFields("MyOtherTable")  very interesting. I was unaware you can call a function while setting it as an object at the same time..

Comment: You're setting your local `dict` variable to the *return value* of the function